# Highcharts Single line series with single data not showing plot

Tags: highcharts

This is a sample workaround of these problems. Whenever I put it on a single date range it does not reflect on the chart but when you hover or click it it's there.

```js
Highcharts.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-c.json', 
  function (data) {
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: data.slice(0,1),
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I think since it's expecting a line it can't be plotted with only one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markers by default are disabled for `normal` state in Highstock. You can easily turn them on:

```
series: [{
  ...,
  marker: {
    enabled: true
  }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4929/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.marker.enabled